# My program continuously goes through a loop in switch case 4. Could someone please take a look and tell me what im doing wrong?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that adds a record to a file in switch case 4 but it continuously goes through a loop. Could someone please help here? I want it to add one record of a student then break out of that case and go into the main menu.

I am new to C programming and not familiar with switch cases. Please take a look and let me know what I need to change.

I think the problem is during the switch case and not the actual code as I did create any loops so I am trying to understand which part of the switch case needs to be changed or if there is a better way to do this.

[image: what happens after I run the code]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

```
int  createFile();
char writeFile();
void mainMenu();

struct Update
{
    char studentName[50];
    int studentID;
    char emailID[100];
    char courseID[5];
    int grade;
} update2;

int main ()
{
  int num;
  
  do
  {
  printf("                   M A I N    M E N U          \n");
  printf("1. Create the Binary File\n");
  printf("2. Display Contents of the file\n");
  printf("3. Seek a specific record\n");
  printf("4. Update the contents of a record\n");
  printf("5. Delete a record for the specific name\n");
  printf("6. Exit\n");



  switch(num)
  {
    case 1:
    createFile();
    break;
    case 4:

    
    writeFile();
    mainMenu();

    break;

    case 6:
    break;
  }

  scanf("%d", &num);
   } while (num != 6);
    return 0;



}

int  createFile() {
    
    
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("BINARY_FILE.txt", "w");

    printf("created file called BINARY_FILE.txt\n");
    return 0;

     }

char writeFile() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("BINARY_FILE.txt", "w");

    int j;
    int i =0;

    
    printf("Enter the studentID\n");
    scanf("%d", &update2.studentID);
    fprintf(fp, "the studentID:%d\n",update2.studentID);

    
    printf("Enter the student name\n");
    scanf("%s", update2.studentName);

    fprintf(fp, "the student name:%s\n",update2.studentName);
    
    printf("Enter the emailID\n");
    scanf("%s", update2.emailID);
    
    fprintf(fp, "the emailID:%s\n",update2.emailID);
    
    printf("Enter the courseID\n");
    scanf("%s", update2.courseID);
    
    fprintf(fp, "the courseID:%s\n", update2.courseID);
    
    printf("Enter the grade\n");
    scanf("%d", &update2.grade);

    fprintf(fp, "the grade:%d\n", update2.grade);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

    }


void mainMenu()
{
     printf("                   M A I N    M E N U          \n");
  printf("1. Create the Binary File\n");
  printf("2. Display Contents of the file\n");
  printf("3. Seek a specific record\n");
  printf("4. Update the contents of a record\n");
  printf("5. Delete a record for the specific name\n");
  printf("6. Exit\n");
}
```

Comment: `num` is uninitialized? Or is there a missing `scanf()` somewhere?

Comment: You should get the scanf to outside as well as inside, or to reorder your code

Comment: You are switching on `num` _before_ reading any value into it.

Comment: _Side note:_ `mashed_potaotes` -> `mashed_potatoes` ???

Comment: Have update my answer. See if the last suggestions help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried compilling and running it and everything worked as excpeted. How are you running the code and which compiller are you using?

Btw, when scanning strings with scanf, you can use the flag %[^\n] instead of %s, as the second one stops after a white space and the first one only stops until (^) a new line (\n) is found. An example of how this could be made is:

```
char writeFile() {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("BINARY_FILE.txt", "w");

    int j;
    int i =0;


    printf("Enter the studentID\n");
    scanf("%d", &update2.studentID);
    fprintf(fp, "the studentID:%d\n",update2.studentID);


    printf("Enter the student name\n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", update2.studentName);

    fprintf(fp, "the student name:%s\n",update2.studentName);

    printf("Enter the emailID\n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", update2.emailID);

    fprintf(fp, "the emailID:%s\n",update2.emailID);

    printf("Enter the courseID\n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", update2.courseID);

    fprintf(fp, "the courseID:%s\n", update2.courseID);

    printf("Enter the grade\n");
    scanf("%d", &update2.grade);

    fprintf(fp, "the grade:%d\n", update2.grade);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I added a screenshot of what happens after I run the code

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for unmasking such *strange* situations are

1. Enable compiler warnings with `-Wall`
2. Debug the programs using a debugger like [`GDB`](https://www.cprogramming.com/gdb.html)/[`LLDB`](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/tutorial.html)(If you are using CLANG toolchain to compile)
3. In case of memory crashes etc. use address sanitizers like [`ASAN`](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

For your particular use case, if you use the first option, you should ideally hit this warning:

```
<source>:20:7: warning: variable 'num' is used uninitialized whenever function 'main' is called [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  int num;
  ~~~~^~~
<source>:34:10: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  switch(num)
         ^~~
<source>:20:10: note: initialize the variable 'num' to silence this warning
  int num;
         ^
          = 0
```

Try understanding why the compiler emitted this warning and then look at your code logic if it makes sense to adhere to that warning (my personal experience: it usually does!). Fix it and then run your code. Once Step#1 is done and still, strange behavior is afoot, move on to Step#2 and so on. Once you've exhausted all steps, SO is a good place to post your troubles/doubts.

You are switching on `num` which is ***uninitialized*** which has a (*very*)high chance of not matching any of your `case` statements since many compilers *might* just initialize it to 0 or it might be some garbage value, both of which aren't met by any `case` statement of yours (Try printing it's value before the `switch`). This brings me to the next point for `switch-case`. Prefer to have a `default` block in your `switch-case` construct to see if there are any unexpected values creeping into your code logic. e.g:

```
switch(num)
{
    case 1:
    createFile();
    break;

    case 4:
    writeFile();
    mainMenu();
    break;

    case 6:
    break;

    default:
    printf("Give me a break!\n");
    break;
}
```

Also, from the screenshot you shared, you are entering the grade as `A` rather than a number. Try entering a number instead of a character, or change your `grade` type to `char` and use `scanf(" %c", &update2.grade);` Note the *extra space* in the format string before `%c`. Quoting from the [`scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) man page:

> The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. To skip white
> space first, use an explicit space in the format.

So basically:

1. Move `scanf()` before `switch` to have an initialized `num`
2. Read in the `grade` member correctly

Also, please consider switching to safer alternatives of `scanf()` and use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) coupled with [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) / [`strtoul()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) / [`strtod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead.